# How to parse a field while setting custom index in ingest node pipeline using set processor

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I have created a custom index using ingest node pipeline. This is how I have done custom indexing

```
   [
   {
     "set": {
       "field": "_index",
       "value": "metricbeat-dev",
       "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace== 'dev'"
     }
   }
 ]
```

Is it possible to include agent version in the index ? Its present as a field in my document.
What I expect is metricbeat-dev-7.15.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can append agent version to index name using set processor. I have consider agent version feild name as `agent.version`

```
[
      {
        "set": {
          "field": "_index",
          "value": "metricbeat-dev-{{agent.version}}",
          "if": "ctx.kubernetes?.namespace== 'dev'"
        }
      }
    ]
```